# Advice for low voltage electrolysis system please

Tags: voltage, electrolysis

I want to setup a simple electrolysis system with an energy source, two cables, a graphite anode and a steel cathode submerged in sea water. A low voltage of exactly 1.23 V needs to be applied over a couple of weeks with as few interruptions as possible.

I only have rudimentary knowledge about electronics. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

The wall sockets at my place deliver 230 V and an AA battery about 1.5 V. How could I reduce the voltage to the required 1.23 V? And what would be the most secure and reliable energy source, keeping in mind that the system stays connected over a couple of weeks?

What hardware should I get for the system? Does the diameter of the cables play a role or is any size fit for the job?

Any help is welcome! Thanks.

**Edit (10 Oct. 2018):**

[image]

**Edit (13 Oct. 2018):**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84299/discussion-on-question-by-st4rb0y-advice-for-low-voltage-electrolysis-system-ple).

Comment: Please edit your question and include the information that you are working on biorock, and include the approximate sizes of the tank and the electrodes.  That belongs in the question rather than the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**You want a bench power supply**

A bench power supply is a box of electronics you plug into the mains, and provides an adjustable current and voltage. They are versatile and easy to use, especially for beginners. They are also generally useful as pieces of equipment to have in the lab as you learn more about electronics.

Here is an example of what they look like: [Tenma 30V 3A supply on Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/tenma/72-2685/bench-power-supply-1-ch-30v-3a/dp/2563981). This isn't a recommendation of what to buy though, you'll need to work out a bit more detail of what you need.

It looks like you're trying to make hydrogen. If so, each amp that the power supply can provide will make very roughly 0.1ml of hydrogen per second, assuming the electrodes are large enough and there is enough overpotential. So you can work out how much current you need from how much hydrogen you want and how long you can wait.

Comment: I'm not trying to make hydrogen, but it's nevertheless gonna be a bi-product of what I'm trying to experiment with. I'm interested in growing calcium carbonate minerals on the cathode. I've read that 1.23V is the ideal voltage for an efficient growth. Thank you for suggesting the bench power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we know what you are working on, it becomes possible to estimate your needs.

You are trying to use electrolysis to grow biorock.  This requires around 1.23V.  Less voltage, and you get no reaction.  With too high a voltage you get wrong chemical reactions and a growth of incorrect minerals on your cathode.

The rate of accretion of the minerals on the cathode depends in the current.  More current= faster growth.

Given that, you want a powersupply that delivers a fixed voltage that you can set down to a little over 1.23V.

The current rating is the next question, and harder to answer.  [This experiment uses tanks and electrodes about the size you mentioned in the comments.](http://repository.ipb.ac.id/jspui/bitstream/123456789/53405/1/1_biorock_b.pdf)  The current used there varies from 1A to 5A, with noticeable differences in accretion rates.

So, a variable voltage powersupply capable of operating down to 1V and supplying up to 5A would seem to be what you need.  The powersupply (30V and 3A maximum) mentioned in another answer would probably do just fine.

---

If I were doing this, I'd set the voltage using the powersupply and vary the current using the anode.

You want to change the current while keeping the voltage fixed.  So, you have to change the resistance.

The size of the cathode is fixed (in real life you'd be growing biorock on a cable, whose length you can't change once it is in place.)

The composition of the seawater is fixed.  You could add salt to lower the resistance in your test tank, but you can't do that in the ocean.

You can vary the size of the anode.  More area in the water gives you a lower resistance, so more current can flow.

You can also lower the resistance by putting the anode closer to the cathode.  If you get them too close, though, you will get uneven accretion on the cathode.

So, your best bet is the anode.   Make it with the highest surface area you can.  Use  multiple smaller ones rather than one big one if you need to.

With an anode with a large surface area, you can vary yhe current by changing how much of it is in the water.  More anode in the water gives a lower resistance, so more current flows for the same voltage.

So:

1. Make some trial runs to see what kind of current range you can get with your anode at various depths.
2. Select a current level for a full test.
3. Set the voltage, and adjust the anode to get your target current.
4. Do your full run, monitoring voltage and current.  Adjust voltage if it drifts, adjust current to maintain your desired level (it **will** change as the anode is consumed.)
5. Make several runs at different current levels (and voltages) to see which gives the fastest growth and the best material.

That's what I would try if I were trying to grow biorock.

I expect there will be some combination of current and voltage that works best.  And, it might also depend on what minerals are dissolved in your seawater, so the results might vary depending on where you get your seawater.

---

Please keep ventilation in mind.  This will create hydrogen and oxygen, and maybe other gasses as well (like chlorine.)  Hydrogen and oxygen are explosive together.  You need a well ventilated place where gasses can't accumulate to do these experiments.

I'm sure you know that, but other people might not.

Comment: First of all , thank you for your elaborate answer! 
Would the current range during the experiments be displayed on the bench power supply or would I need to get another "probe". If so, where should I take the current measurements?
Using a couple smaller anodes would in fact be ideal. How do I connect more than one to the power supply? Can I just split a single cable, like a tree (for a lack of a better metaphor) and connect the anodes to its "offshoots"?

Comment: Many powersupplies have a built in meter to measure current.  If the power supply doesn't have one, then you could put a multimeter with current measuring ability in series with the powersupply (standard thing to do, should be easy to find examples of how to measure current on the internet.)  How you physically connect multiple anodes depends on how your anodes are built.  You will at any rate haveva way to connect a wire to an anode.  So, connect a wire to each anode then connect all of the wires together and then connect that to the powersupply

Comment: It might be easier to connect a bunch of anodee mechanically together (some kind of clamping system that also conducte electricity.)  Then you connect the wire to the clamp.  I think you will need to go this way if you are going to regulate the current by insertion depth of the anodes.  It is easier to work with if you can move all the anodes together

Comment: Almost forgot:  I think you will find that the current needed depends on the cathode surface area.   So calculate amperes divided by surface area of the cathode to get amperes per square centimeter.  This number will be more useful than just the amperage.  It will help when you change cathode sizes.  Amperes per square centimeter will let you scale the needed current to match the size of different cathodes.

Comment: Thank you, for your great help so far! 
I'm still not sure on how to "split" the cable that runs from the power source and has to provide 1.23 V at 5 or more titanium anodes (cf. diagram above). Can I just physically connect all the cables together? What would be an elegant solution to splice, let's say 5 cables (coming from the anodes) into one cable continuing to the power supply. Won't the voltage be decreased by doing this?

Comment: Putting multiple anodes in parallel won't change the voltage.  I'd make a frame so I could clamp all the anodes together mechanically - raising and lowering the frame then raises and lowers all the anodes together so that you can regulate the current.  If the frame is of insulating material (wood or plastic) then you connect a wire to each anode and connect them all together and connect that to the powersupply.  If the frame is made of metal, then you clamp all the anodes into it then connect the frame to the powersupply with one wire.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks! My plan is to build a circular frame with evenly distributed anodes on it's perimeter (like points on an evenly divided circle). The mineral accumulating cathode would be "floating" in its center. Would this be efficient or should the anodes rather be clustered together (close to one another). In my scenario, they are offset by around 3 to 4 cm minimum distance between an anode and its neighbours. The diagonal distances would be bigger (ca. diameter of the circular frame).

Comment: You are probably right to space them further apart.  I was thinking of them bunched up, but that's probably not the best.

Comment: OK, have a nice week-end!